# Replace only certain '%' in a string

Tags: php, string

I am using `str_replace()` to replace all the slashes in a string with '%' and then I run the newly edited string through a function. One of the things this function does is adds '%%%' to the string.

Now, I need to replace only the percentage signs that I replaced before, that were slashes before, with slashes again.

So if the original string looks like this: '`the/wuick/bornw/foc/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog.`'

After passing it through the function it will look like this: '`The%quick%brown%fox%jumps%over%the/lazy%dog.%%%`'

And then after putting it through the part I need help with, it will look like this: '`The/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog.%%%`'

I would greatly appreciate any and all help replacing only the % that I had done with `str_replace()` before.

Comment: Show us your function. There is no reason for it to add "%%%" at the end of the string, and it is best to remove that part instead of "fixing" it afterwards.

Comment: In the general case this is of course not possible (I am assuming "%%% at the end" was just an example, as otherwise you could simply remove that with `substr`).

Comment: tell us what you are trying to solve with this 3 steps approach, if you're using the % as placeholders only then there are better solutions to your problem

Comment: @Sven I would prefer not to show the function as it is quite long and I don't want to give each line 4 spaces to put it into SO.

Comment: @Sven But, true. I should just remove that part.

Comment: @Jon It is 3 of the symbol that was originally put in place of the slashes.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson, just btw, you can select your code, and click an icon in the header's editor, that indents the code for you.

Answer (score 4):

To replace single `%` signs with slashes, you can use

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!%)%(?!%)/', '/', $subject);
```

This uses [negative lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure only those `%` signs are matched that are neither preceded nor followed by another `%` sign.

See it on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/xR8kW3).

Comment: I was honestly just seeing if it was possible in PHP to replace only certain characters in a string without replacing all of them. Is this possible in PHP? And without me knowing what could be or is before and after them?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this doing just what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, but what I described in the question was just an example. What I was wondering how to do is get the position of the / that I replace, replace those to %, then pass to function 1, then replace only those %, at the string positions, to /, then pass to function 2.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson: Well, that's a completely different question from what you actually asked. I suggest you open a new question for this. Please be as specific as possible. For example, in your comment, there was no mention at all of the `%%%` addition to your string. It would be relevant to know if that is still relevant, and whether such an addition would only occur at the end of the string or possibly in other positions, too (because that would change the position of the replaced slashes!)...

Answer (score 0):

without too many complications execute in this order:

```
$str = 'The%quick%brown%fox%jumps%over%the/lazy%dog.%%%';
$str= str_replace('%%%','***triple_percent**', $str);
$str= str_replace('%','/', $str);
$str= str_replace('***triple_percent**','%%%', $str);
```

Idealy first see why you have so many %, I am sure you can simplify your functions.

Another solution is using regular expressions like Tim says in his answer

```
$str= preg_replace('/(?<!%)%(?!%)/', '/', $str);
```

Break apart means:

```
(?<!%)     Not % before
%          find %
(?!%)      Not % after
```

also add g so it can find it many times, and i for case sensitive in the case that you might need it:

```
$str= preg_replace('/(?<!%)%(?!%)/ig', '/', $str);
```

Comment: I honestly just was seeing if only replacing certain symbols in a string with many of said character was possible. This was just an example.

Comment: Oh yes it is possible using regexp, but each case is different, in my example you go step by step, with regex you need to know the exact format to create the expresion

Comment: I read your comment and couldn't figure out what regex + p was and then I realised it was just short for regular expressions. What if I don't know the exact format?

Comment: give me a more general example and we can figure it out, read my answer again, I added comments about what is means.

Comment: Thank you. Let's see. Input '2/2 is 4 not 4%', then I use str_replace to convert it to '2%2 is 4 not 4%'. And now what I need help with is converting the original '/' back to a '/'. So the final string is '2/2 is 4 not 4%'. I need this to work because I pass the second version to one function and the final version to another. One understands division by '/' or understand '%' for division.

Answer (score -1):

Add another replate with blank string like:

```
$string = str_replace('%', '', $string);
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything but replace all the % symbols with nothing. I need only some of % symbols to be replaced.